# how to handle App Active/inactive State with pushkit

Tags: ios, push-notification, pushkit

I am using Pushkit for save data from notification and showing local notification after saving Data.

For Example :- I am sending 10 pushkit notifications to device.

when 1st local notification arrives, the app Automatically comes into Active state then I am not getting any other Local notification.

**1.) How can I manage Active/inactive state with Pushkit?**

**2.) How to handle Local notification with Pushkit ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you had pushkit payload then scheduling local notification, in that case your app will be active till your local notification sound file plays. ( Max 30 seconds )

While receiving payload in `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` you can check apps state.

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background
{

}
```

Go through this whole article, specially written for Push kit and local notification for Video calling based app.

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification